# Is there any algorithm (if possible, I need the codes) for Jordan normal form decomposition for large matrices in practice?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, computational-mathematics, matrix-calculus

Although it is an ill-posed problem as B Kågström said in "An algorithm for numerical computation of the Jordan normal form of a complex matrix", I wonder what people do when they need to do Jordan decomposition in real life. For example, how to decompose a 1000*1000 real matrix( we may only consider the case that all eigenvalues are real).

Comment: What real-life application do you need the Jordan decomposition for? Usually you want to SVD instead.

Comment: If we write a matrix in JNF, then some optimization problem will be easily solved. So I wonder if there exist such algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical algorithms avoid making use of the Jordan canonical form for exactly the reason you mention: the Jordan form is not continuous in the entries of the matrix. But if you're *sure* you need it for your application, a starting point is Beelen & Dooren 1990 and the references therein: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.3971&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thank you. It helps a lot.

Comment: Hello. I still have one question. Is there any code for Jordan decomposition except Matlab, which is too slow?

Comment: I'm not aware of any C or Fortran code, unfortunately. You might also try asking on the Computational Science stackexchange.